# Get values corresponding to key inside array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is [array of objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5Vhs.jpg) from which , i want to get value corresponding to keys , for e.g `"ERROR"` in this case for key `status`. This status may come at any index of array of objects. How do filter throughout array and get key and values.

i have `response` object which gives dynamic array objects from which  i can get by using `Object.values(response)[0].responseStatus.status`
for some case `Object.values(response)[0].status` . How do get using programmatically using jquery.

Comment: It would be much better to post the actual data, rather than a screenshot of the data

Comment: Don't post the information from your console. Post the actual code.

Comment: @RobM. see edits

Comment: Try `let status = Object.values(response)[0].status || Object.values(response)[0].responseStatus.status` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function findValueByKey(obj, key, out) {
var i, proto = Object.prototype,ts = proto.toString,
hasOwn = proto.hasOwnProperty.bind(obj);
if ('[object Array]' !== ts.call(out)) out = [];
for (i in obj) {
    if (hasOwn(i)) {
        if (i === key) {
            out.push(obj[i]);
        } else if ('[object Array]' === ts.call(obj[i]) || 
                '[object Object]' === ts.call(obj[i])) {
            findValueByKey(obj[i], key, out);
        }
    }
  }
 return out;
}
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm understanding your question you want to iterate over the keys in an object and output their values. You're looking for something like this:

```
var keyOutputter = function(obj){
    var keys = Object.keys(obj)
    for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
       var key = keys[i]
       console.log(key + ":" obj[key])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take any idea from this

```
$.each(responseStatus, function(index,value){
  if(value.status == "ERROR"){
    var valueIndex = index;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to find the value of some property in your response object. Using plain JavaScript I would do something like this:

```js
//our data object
var responseStatus = {
  status: "ERROR",
  description: "createUserPassword invalid input",
  errorData: ['first error desc', 'the second error desc.']
};

//used to get the value of specific property an object
function getObjectProperty(desiredPropertyKey, dataObject) {
  for (prop in dataObject) {
    if (dataObject.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      if (prop === desiredPropertyKey) {
        return dataObject[prop];
      }
    }
  }
}

//use function defined above to get the 'status' value in our response obj
function getResponseStatus() {
  return getObjectProperty('status', responseStatus);
}

function getResponseDescription() {
  return getObjectProperty('description', responseStatus);
}

console.log(getResponseStatus());
console.log(getResponseDescription());
```